# PHP: Match corresponding file names

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

This one may be a bit of a doozy.

I have 2 sets of files in separate folders:
SET 1:

- celeb1.png
- celeb2.png
- celeb3.png
- celeb4.png
- celeb5.png

etc

The user selects an image (radio) and I then set this as a get variable on the url:

Now, I want to match another file.

In another folder, I have a set like this:

SET 2:

- celeb1-24_59_250_300.png
- celeb2-35_67_200_250.png
- celeb3-54_87_300_400.png
- celeb4-88_98_250_350.png
- celeb5-87_43_300_400.png

etc

I want to use the GET variable (i.e.) celeb1.png, and then select the full filename of the corresponding file, based on the first 5 characters.

In other words if $_GET['celebimg'] is 'celeb1.png', I want to set a second variable (let's say $overlay) to string 'celeb1-24_59_250_300.png'

Any idea on how to achieve that?

I could obviously do a switch, but that means I would have to update the code every time a new celeb image is uploaded.

Is there any dynamic way to achieve this?

Thanks

JG

Comment: Look at [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. Since we haven't seen what you have tried so far. This is just an illustration. However the code has been tested.

```
<?php
$file='celeb3.png'; // Here is where you will get the param $_GET['set1']

$set2=array(
    'celeb1-24_59_250_300.png',
    'celeb2-35_67_200_250.png',
    'celeb3-54_87_300_400.png',
    'celeb4-88_98_250_350.png',
    'celeb5-87_43_300_400.png'
          );

$set1 = explode('.',$file);
//echo $set1[0];//celeb3

foreach($set2 as $val)
{
    if($set1[0]==substr($val,0,strlen($set1[0])))
    {
        echo $val;//celeb3-54_87_300_400.png
        break;
    }
}
```

> **OUTPUT** : celeb3-54_87_300_400.png

Comment: This worked like a dream Shankar, one up!

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob` to search a folder

```
//Get the GET variable
$cimg = $_GET['celebimg'];

//split it so we can just get the name without extention
$nameparts = explode(".",$cimg);

//glob will try to find matches to the string passed 
$matches = glob("/dir/path/{$nameparts[0]}-*.png");
```

`$matches` will be an array of matched files

you could use other file functions like `scandir` or `readdir` etc but those do not filter out the files so you would have to do it.